# Is there a simplest way to solve function code as stated below

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

Define a function that accepts a list (called numbers below) as input and return a list where each element is multiplied by 10. The grader will supply the argument numbers to the function when you run the grader.score.in__problem2 method below.
In this case, you need to write a function that will work for arbitrary input. Before submitting your function to the grader, you may want to check that it returns the output that you expect by evaluating code similar to the following:

```
test_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
mult(test_numbers)

def mult(numbers):
    return [0] * len(numbers)

grader.score.in__problem2(mult)
```

Comment: Why is this not simple enough?

Comment: @PCM Let's save few more bytes 

Comment: Show your attempt, along with a *specific* question about what you don't understand.  Don't just post a verbatim description of your homework, with no attempt to solve it.

Comment: looks like a exercise

Answer (score 0):

In our python we can iterate over lists, by using this feature we can multiply or can perform any action in list elements, as per my understanding of your problem, i am providing this solution.

```
z=[1,2,3]
#function to iterate and multiplay 
def mult(arg):
    for item in arg:
        arg[arg.index(item)]=item*10
    return arg
    
new = mult(z)
print(z)#old list elements
print(new)#new list elements
```

**output:**

```
[1,2,3]
[10,20,30]
```

**theory:**
-read the concept of iterables in python
-iterate over given list perform actions
-return the updated list from function